# select second lowest date in table

Tags: r

I want to filter the second lowest date. I´m familiar with the min/max functions, but they are not applicable here.

```
DF<-tibble::tribble(
         ~date,
  "2019-01-01",
  "2019-01-02",
  "2019-01-03",
  "2019-01-04",
  "2019-01-05",
  "2019-01-06",
  "2019-01-07",
  "2019-01-08",
  "2019-01-09",
  "2019-01-10",
  "2019-01-11",
  "2019-01-12",
  "2019-01-13",
  "2019-01-14"
  )

DF$date<-as.Date(DF$date)
```

Desired output:

```
2009-01-02
```

Anyone? :)

Comment: If you can sort I would go for that otherwise if for some reason you do not want to sort filter out the min and take the min again could do the job too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little lateral thinking gives this solution using the tidyverse.

The logic is to sort the dates from lowest to highest (`arrange`), select the earliest two (`head`) and then take the latest of the two selected (`max`).

```
> DF %>% arrange(date) %>% head(2) %>% pull(date) %>% max()
[1] "2019-01-02"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `order` in this way.

```
DF$date[order(as.Date(DF$date)) == 2]
# [1] "2019-01-02"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sort`, `head` and `tail` like so.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF$date %>% sort() %>% head(2) %>% tail(1)

#[1] "2019-01-02"
```